# Handling data stream with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We are building our client application using React and the application state is manage by Redux. What we intend to do is to register with an external data stream such that whenever new data is emitted, the application state should be updated.

Can Redux directly register with the server stream or do we need to use any redux middleware to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In a Redux application, middleware is the standard place to handle external connections like websockets.  There's numerous existing middlewares for handling websockets and specific services like Firebase.  See the ["Middleware - Sockets and Adapters"](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md#sockets-and-adapters) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a reference to your Redux store and call `dispatch`.

Here's a snippet using socket.io

```
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

// ... some code to initialize socket.io

socket.on('receiveAction', data => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'ACTION_TYPES',
    payload: data
  });
});
```

If you need it from a separate file just export/import the store.

Comment: Do I need to do it using socket ? Does't Redux provide any out of box support for this ?

Comment: Socket is just an example. You can call dispatch anywhere as long as you have reference to the store

Comment: @krajwade There is no OOTB support for streams particularly.